# I need help with total capacity of rear derailleur

Tags: derailleur, drivetrain

I am unsure how to calculate the total capacity for a 1x drivetrain, I have 46t up front and 11-32 10 speed cassette.

How can I determine which derailleur will work with this setup? E-mtb build.

I was looking at the Shimano Saint and Deore XT, Saint has total capacity of 25t and Deore Xt has 47t.

Also should I go long or medium or short cage? Deore XT is long cage and Saint is short cage but has a 'wide option' to run an 11-32 cassette for freeride use, I would be using it on quite a high powered emtb so maybe this isnt ideal?

Answer (score 5):

You only need 21t total capacity (32-11).

If you are looking at currently produced mountain rear derailleurs, the conversation here isn't about total capacity, because they all have more than that. If 11-32 is really what you want to be running, what's in question is choosing from the relatively few Shimano mountain 10 RDs that both are desirable for narrow range 1x (has a clutch and a short cage) and where 32 isn't less than the minimum for their low cog clearance. You would go to the [spec tables](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/spec/MTB/Rear%20Derailleur) to find options. Saint RD-M820-SS is the best out there that meets this criteria.

For the cage length, shorter is always better if you don't need what a long cage gives you, which is more total capacity. Your total capacity needs are about as low as it gets with 11-32 on 1x, so short cage is ideal.

If you tried to cheat the minimum low cog, you would likely find that even with the b-screw all the way out, the guide pulley is further away from the cogs than ideal, and shifting will suffer.

Comment: Very helpful thank you, in your opinion am I right to go for a 10 speed 11-32 for quite a high powered e-bike?

Comment: @Confused I would only consider going with such a narrow range if your terrain is very flat. If this is a mid drive I think the most prudent choice is use an off the shelf Linkglide group.

Comment: I've placed an order for the complete Linkglide drivetrain now, thank you so much for bringing it to my attention as it sounds ideal.

Comment: Just regarding tyres, would you know if I could get away with 2.0" tyres on a 30mm rim or should I go around 2.2" - 2.7"?

Comment: 2.0 is fine on 30mm

Comment: You've been so helpful, my Shimano 11 speed Linkglide drivetrain arrived yesterday and its beautiful, exactly what I was looking and I've ordered my 2.0 tyres too. Thank you very much